# JavaScript false/null var inside if clause

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

What kind of variables will **NOT** pass through this:

`if(myVar){//code}`

Boolean false? NULL? Boolean false and NULL? Anything else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the following *falsy* values as:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- `0`
- `""` <sub>(an empty string)</sub>
- `false`

Anything else converted to Boolean will yield `true`.

More info:

- [`ToBoolean`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.2) internal operation

Comment: @lincolnk: if `myVar` is **undeclared** you will get a `ReferenceError`. A variable can be declared and hold `undefined` as its value, for example, when you declare a variable without initialize it with a value: `var myVar;` it will be **declared**, but uninitialized, it will hold `undefined` as its value, e.g. `alert(myVar);` will alert `"undefined"`. At some point you can also assign the `undefined` value to it, e.g. `myVar = undefined;`. Remember, **undeclared** != `undefined`

Comment: ok, that all makes sense. `typeof <undeclared name>` produces 'undefined' in IE, which is throwing me off.

Comment: @lincolnk: Yeah, if the operand expression of the [`typeof` operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.4.3) is an *unresolvable reference* (it doesn't exist in the scope chain), will explicitly return the string `"undefined"`.

Comment: - Note that all the above are *primitive values*, any object, even the Boolean object wrappers will always produce `true`, e.g.: `if (new Boolean(false)) { alert('Javascript FTW!'); }` -

Comment: Wow, lots of errors can happen if you don't know this. Thanks a lot, CMS, much appreciated.

Comment: Hm, what would "0" (string 0) yield? And are the values specified in your answer cross-browser consistent?

Comment: @Francisc: A string, converted to Boolean will produce `false` **only** when its length is `0` (an empty string), that's not the case of `"0"` (it's length is `1`). You can test this easily simply by `alert(!!"0");` or `alert(Boolean("0"));` which will give you `true`. And yes, the values I describe are based on the ECMAScript language specification, they are implemented cross-browser consistently.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. After reading the link you provided I saw it said "false if the argument is the empty String".